# Reload angularjs directive after ajax page load?

Tags: jquery, ajax, angularjs, angularjs-directive

My basic HTML is like:

```
<body ng-controller="ContentCtl">
    <section id="page_content">
        ### HOME PAGE ###
    </section>
</body>
```

On the home page, I click to navigate to another page which just changes the content of #page_content using jQuery, in short something like:

```
gl.prototype.pageNav = function(page) {
    $.ajax({
        url: page,
        success: function (data) {
            $('#page_content').html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

On one sub-page, I have an angular directive being used:

```
<div id="awesomeSubPage" ng-my-sub-directive></div>
```

However, it seems the directive doesn't get called after ajax page navigation, it does get called if I go directly to the page like: site.com/myApp/awesomeSubPage

The code for the directive is:

```
myApp.controller('ContentCtrl', function($scope) {
    // commented out
}.directive('ngMySubDirective', function() {
    return {
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            elem.on('load', function () {
                console.log('Run ngMySubDirective postMessage');
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a particular reason you are using jQuery to change the content? If you are creating an AngularJs app then you could just use the Angularjs Routing module to display a different view.

The reason the directive does not work in your case is that by using jQuery, you are outside the "Angular world". So Angular does not know that the content has changed. You can call `$scope.$apply` if you really need to. You can also just replace that call to `$.ajax` with a call using `$http` as mentioned [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/When-to-use-$scope.$apply())

Comment: It's a ZF2 app that we had completed with jQuery and have started adding angular but will take a while before we can fully remove jQuery things (lots of dependencies etc.)

Comment: Updated answer. If possible replace just the ajax call. If that is not possible, then call $scope.$apply yourself after the ajax call.

Comment: When I try to replace `$.ajax` with `$http` - I get `$http not defined` - how do I 'add angular' into my custom JS? As we have one file that was mostly jQuery, and now another file that handles angularjs, do I need to call the app name first? like `myApp.$http` ?

Comment: Ah, if that's the situation you're in then things are more complicated. You can't just "add angular" to your jQuery code. I don't know the structure of your application but it would be better to try and convert a whole section to Angular rather than parts of a page.

Comment: Hmm, I had used: `angular.element('#logo').scope().$emit('ajax.pagechange.complete');` inside the `$.ajax({success: func()})` call, however it doesn't work now that I've changed to: `var $http = angular.element('body').injector().get('$http'); $http({}).success(func() {});`

Comment: I've moved as much 'legacy JS' to angular, still a lot to convert but it's working better :)

Ideally, need to figure out a way to remove the $compile() line I use when I change pages via $http... I don't have angularjs templates, only ZF2 and don't want to move away from it.